# Sin and Cosine chart plotter.....some algorithm errors C++

Tags: c++, plot, trigonometry

So i've created this chart plotting program here. However I am having a few glitches with it. First I should describe how this program is to work. Basically using stdscr and creating a new win I have to create a "function generator" program. Charcaters will be printed on the screen which will emulate the sin and cosine waveforms. As the characters roll down the window the window will scroll. One of the windows will contain the frame (header, lines, footer). The other window will be the one that will scroll and print the sine and cosine waveforms. I've been checking over my code for along time now and whatever it is that im faulting, I cannot figure out.

If your still having trouble envisioning the program think of pong...2 vertical lines top and bottom and then a line running through the middle. And on this "court"/screen the sine and cosine waves will be printing.

My error is that sin and cosine aren't printing the way i want to...it seems they are going out of the bounds of the Newwin window. Also the footer which will designate from 1 0 -1 will not move to the position I want it in the footer.

```
#include <curses.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "fmttime.h"
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

enum colors
        {
        BLACK,
        RED,
        GREEN,
        YELLOW,
        BLUE,
        MAGENTA,
        CYAN,
        WHITE,
        };

void Sim_Advance(int degrees);          // Function prototype declarations
double Sim_Cos();
double Sim_Sin();
void frame(const char* title, int gridcolor, int labelcolor);
void mark(WINDOW* window, char ch, int color, double value);

static const double PI = (3.1415927/180); // Degrees to radian factor
static double PA = 0;                   // Phase angle
static int x;                           // X dimension of screen
static int y;                           // Y dimension of screen
static int delay1 = 300000;             // 300ms Delay

struct timeval tv;                      // Timeval object declaration

int main(void)
{
    initscr();                          // Curses.h initilizations
    cbreak();
    nodelay(stdscr, TRUE);
    noecho();


    int keyhit;
    int ctr = 1;                        // Exit flag
    int degrees = 10;                   // Interval to be added to phase
    int tempcounter = 1;
    char buf[32];                       // Buffer being sent to formattime
    size_t len = sizeof(buf);           // Size of buffer being passed
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);            // calling function for epoch time
    formatTime(&tv, buf, len);          // Calling formaTime for timestamp

    getmaxyx(stdscr,y,x);
    WINDOW* Window = newwin(y-4, x-2, 2, 5);
    scrollok(Window, TRUE);
    char cTitle[] = {"Real time Sine/ Cosine Plot"};  // Title string for plot


        while (ctr == 1)                // This will run the program till
        {                               // exit is detected (CTRL-X)
            usleep(delay1/6);           // Delays program execution
            keyhit = getch();

            mark(Window,'C', WHITE, Sim_Cos());


            mark(Window,'S', RED, Sim_Sin());

            Sim_Advance(degrees);       // Advances PA by "degrees" value (10)

                if (tempcounter == 1)
                {
                    frame(cTitle, WHITE, RED);  // Prints out the frame once
                    --tempcounter;
                }

                if (keyhit == 24)
                {
                    ctr = 0;            // Exit flag set
                }
        }
    endwin();
    return 0;
}

// Function will advance the Phase angle by assigned value of degrees
// The value of degrees must be an int and must be in radians

void Sim_Advance(int degrees)
{
    PA = PA + degrees;

    if (PA >=  360)
    {
        PA = PA - 360;

    }
}

// Calculates the Cos of the Phase angle and returns value to main

double Sim_Cos()
{
    double PARad;                       // Need to convert degrees into Radian
    PARad = (PA*PI);

    return cos(PARad);
}

// Calculates the Sin of the Phase angle and returns value to main

double Sim_Sin()
{
    double PARad2;                      // Variable to hold radian value
    PARad2 = (PA*PI);
    return sin(PARad2);
}

// Will print the grid and Axis of the display as well as a title for the display
// with variable background and/or foreground colors

void frame(const char* title, int gridcolor, int labelcolor)
{

    int offset = 27/2;                  // Middle of string
    int col = 0;
    int row = 0;
    int botline = 0;

    start_color();
    init_pair(0, labelcolor, BLACK);
    init_pair(1, gridcolor, BLACK);

    wmove(stdscr, 0, (x / 2)- offset);


    wprintw(stdscr,"%s\n", title);
    wrefresh(stdscr);

    while (row != x)                    // This prints the top line
    {
        attrset(COLOR_PAIR(1));
        wprintw(stdscr,"-");

        wrefresh(stdscr);
        ++row;
    }

    while (col != y-4)                  // This prints the middle line
    {
        wmove(stdscr, col + 2, x/2);
        wprintw(stdscr, "|\n");
        wrefresh(stdscr);
        ++col;
    }

    while (botline != x)                // Prints the bottom line
    {
        wprintw(stdscr, "-");
        wrefresh(stdscr);
        ++botline;
    }

    attrset(COLOR_PAIR(0));

    wmove(stdscr, y, 0);                // These three things commands
    wprintw(stdscr, "-1");              // Will print out the proper footer
    wrefresh(stdscr);


    wmove(stdscr, y, x/2);
    wprintw(stdscr, "0");
    wrefresh(stdscr);


    wmove(stdscr, y, x);
    wprintw(stdscr, "1");
    wrefresh(stdscr);

}

// Will print out the characters passed to it in the designated
// window to which it points to.

void mark(WINDOW* window, char ch, int color, double value)
{
    int cursep = (((x/2) * value) + (x/2)); // Prints character from middle
    int currenty = getcury(window);         // of screen
    wmove(window, currenty+1, cursep-3);    // Moves cursor to desired location
    wrefresh(window);
    usleep(delay1);
    waddch(window, ch);
    wrefresh(window);
}
```

Comment: Get rid of the line numbers in your code post. They make it near-impossible to debug from our side.

Comment: Oops sorry, Edited without the numbers!

Answer (score 0):

Partial solution (a simplified post would help OP and SO)

1. Use `double PI = (M_PI/ 180);`  or 3.141592653589793/180
2. Converting positive double to int rounds down,  negative double to int rounds up.   So avoid double to int on both sides of 0.
3. Width is `x`.  Think of screen as `x` boxes across.  The *center* of box 0 is for value of -1.0.  The *center* of box x-1 is for value of +1.0.  Thus from center to center is a distance of x-1 boxes.

Change

```
int cursep = (((x / 2) * value) + (x / 2));
```

to

```
void mark() {
...
// value = -1.0 --> cursep = 0
// value = +1.0 --> cursep = x - 1
// ** Adjust these 4 vars as needed to re-map your translation **
double val_min = -1.0;
double val_max = +1.0;
int  cur_min = 0;
int  cur_max = x - 1;
//  y = (y1-y0)/(x1-x0)*(x-x0) + y0
double cur_d = (cur_max - cur_min)/(val_max - val_min)*(value - val_min) + cur_min;
int cursep = floor(cur_d + 0.5);
```

4 Not clear about `-3` in `wmove(window, currenty + 1, cursep - 3);`